# There are only two groups of order six, up to isomorphism: $\mathbb Z_6$ and $S_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ be  group with order $6$. Prove that either $G$ and $\Bbb Z_{6}$ are isomorphic binary structure or $G$ and $S_{3}$ are isomorphic binary structure.

I know that for isomorphic binary structure, we define a function between groups and we should check homomorphism property and bijection. But I can not define a function between them. Please help me, if you have any good idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Either your group has an element of order $6$ or not. If it has, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Otherwise, which are the possible orders of elemets of $G$?

Comment: Please start at least cursory efforts to look for duplicates of questions *before* you answer them.  This is a rather standard question which you'd expect to have been asked on this site before, multiple times.

Comment: @amWhy This time, I did search for a duplicate.

Comment: Okay, I'm fine with that.  I changed the title of the question so that it, like its duplicate, is more readily accessible in the future for similar questions.

Comment: @amWhy I had never thought of that. That's a good idea.